# Using SIP "Session Initiation Protocol" (Skype for Business) through Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, sip, skype-for-business

Has anyone had any experience connecting a Skype for Business Edge server through a data flow management tool, ideally Apache NiFi? At the moment I am only interested in instant messaging, so audio chunking and stuff isn't an issue and latency introduced by me messing with things on NiFi also isnt an issue.

Currently I have spun up a test Skype for Business Edge server and pointing it at a test Apache Nifi server, which is listening to the applicable TCP port (5061). With some fun with TLS 1.2, I have it sending me "SIP 2.0 Negotiate" packets, but I have no experience whatsoever with SIP, so don't really know what I am doing.

My next plan was to write some Python code using a library like SipSimple or Sippy, but wanted to post on here to see if anyone has any ideas.

Also to note - i am happy to accept answers such as "Skype shouldnt be connected to Nifi, its stupid", but that not really in the Christmas spirit is it :D